# Compile ModSecurity 3.3 with YAJL

Tags: centos, mod-security, libraries, headers, compilation

anyone could help? I'm stucked on this.

I already compiled ModSecurity 3.3 on this machine (followed [these instructions](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/)). Now I'm trying to compile with YAJL (Yet Another JSON Library) to be able to log in JSON format.

I installed yajl and yajl-devel packages with yum. My system is a CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core).

Some detail about the system and YAJL files present:

```
[root@nginx ModSecurity]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/include:/usr/lib64

[root@nginx ModSecurity]# ls /usr/lib64 | grep yajl
libyajl.so
libyajl.so.2
libyajl.so.2.0.4

[root@nginx ModSecurity]# ls /usr/include/yajl/ | grep yajl
yajl_common.h
yajl_gen.h
yajl_parse.h
yajl_tree.h
yajl_version.h
```

Output of two variations of `./configure --with-yajl`:

```
[root@nginx ModSecurity]# ./configure --with-yajl=/usr/include/yajl/
.... output ommited ....
configure: YAJL headers found at: /usr/include/yajl/
configure: error: YAJL was explicitly referenced but it was not found
.... output ommited ....

[root@nginx ModSecurity]# ./configure --with-yajl=/usr/lib64/
.... output ommited ....
configure: YAJL library found at: /usr/lib64///libyajl.so
configure: error: YAJL was explicitly referenced but it was not found
.... output ommited ....
```

Comment: Don't add `--with-yajl` at all, let it figure on its own.

Comment: You were right. This worked. The problem was that I didn’t knew that had to use “make clear” to delete old objects and thus allow “make” to compile again.